# 生抽 vs. 酱油- differences?

Tags: word-choice, difference

I was looking at this recipe here: https://www.xinshipu.com/zuofa/9787, and noticed the word "生抽“. After inputting it in various online translators, they all said it meant soy sauce. However, the recipe calls for both 生抽 AND 酱油 as separate ingredients, and it wouldn't make sense to require soy sauce twice. Am I just misreading the recipe or are they different things? What better translation is there for 生抽？

Comment: Jacky is right about it being *light soy sauce* in English, a lot of times you'll see the Japanese name also: *usukuchi*.

Comment: 生抽 and 酱油 seems like a mistake - the comma should be omitted, as it's just 生抽酱油. However the recipe calls for the two to be used differently, so they are intended as different things - which I'd say was indicative of poor kitchen / recipe-writing skills.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**生抽**酱油 (light soy sauce) and **老抽**酱油 (dark soy sauce) are two different types of 酱油 (soy sauce). **生抽** is the abbreviation of **生抽**酱油 while **老抽** is the abbreviation of **老抽**酱油, **酱** is the abbreviation of **酱油**, **酱** also refer to a general name of all kinds of **sauces**.

Comment: Sauces? Not sources?

Comment: @user3306356 thanks, I also found it and corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

`生抽酱油` (light soy sauce) is salty and light in color, it add flavor to dishes in cooking
`老抽酱油` (dark soy sauce) is less salty and dark in color, it make dishes dark brown in color.
  [Click for more Info](https://www.thespruceeats.com/dark-soy-sauce-694243)

Answer (score 1):

bkrs
:**生抽** light soy sauce (Russ) superior quality,white, fresh, liquid, soy sauce, iciba: light soy sauce
**酱油** soy sauce cf. 生抽 (extracted raw),酱 paste, jam, dial. dense

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the dumpling recipe you linked, both 生抽 AND 酱油 refer to light soy sauce. It is very uncommon to use dark soy sauce for dumpling fillings or dumpling dipping sauce.

Answer (score 0):

酱油 is a generic term that covers several sauces made from fermented food (mainly soy), but can also be used to refer to 生抽.

生抽 and 老抽 are two different kind of sauces made from fermented soy beans. 生抽 is very salty and is used to add savory taste. 老抽 is much milder and is used to add color.